# How to set layout for errorhandler dynamically without module

Tags: php, yii2

I am new in Yii2,

When I started creating a website, i found that you can set ErrorAction in configuration like this

```
 'errorHandler' => [
            'errorAction' => 'site/error',

        ],
```

That error using layout from layout/main.php. That layout was used when guest visit the page that located in 'view/site'. But when the user log in the view page locate in different folder which is 'view/band' the layout become totally different and using 'layout/BandLayout'. I know that you can change layout dynamically in controller like i did in BandController

```
public $layout ='BandLayout';
```

That will change the entire layout in 'view/band'. But when there is an error like '404' the layout still using layout from layout/main.php. I have done some searching but the solution using init() in module. Since i have not learn module, how do I set layout for error layout in controller?

Thank you

Comment: Have also a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43761325/57091

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should change layout in `SiteController`, you could use `beforeAction`, e.g. :

```
public function beforeAction($action)
{
    if (parent::beforeAction($action)) {
        // change layout for error action
        if ($action->id=='error')
             $this->layout ='BandLayout';
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it is work! but can you explain why we change the layout in SiteController instead BandController?

Comment: If you dont mind, would you see my next question in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27576197/how-to-change-table-users-in-loginform. Thanks

Comment: after lots of time waste got your answer and its works perfectly fine, many thanks